# What is the earliest story or book combining technological FTL communication with lack of FTL travel?

Tags: history-of, communication

What is the earliest story or book combining technology for FTL communication with a lack of FTL travel?

I first remember encountering this concept in Orson Scott Card's Ender's Game:

> ("Ender's Game"): After the war, when Valentine meets Ender and tells
> him that she will be going to the first colony, Ender says "It's fifty
> years to get there". Her answer, "Only two years if you're aboard the
> ship".

> ("Speaker for the Dead"),  "Lightspeed travel", and later, on the
> trip to Lusitania, it is mentioned "the only task was to calculate how
> near to lightspeed the ship was traveling".

The ansible, however, provided near-instantaneous communication.

I then encountered this in Ursula LeGuin's Hainish cycle. The Hainish cycle predates the Ender series, beginning I believe in 1966.  (As a matter of fact, Orson Scott Card mentions that he got the idea, and the 'ansible' name, from the Hainish cycle.  See http://www.hatrack.com/questions/ and search for "Hainish".)

It seems to me that this creative combination would have a unique effect on the world/universe being described, culture, etc., as the dynamics of instantaneous (or, almost) communication, but needing years to get to different star systems (and the relativistic effects thereof) are quite different than either FTL travel & communication or STL travel & communication.

Since what I find unique/interesting about this is the unique influences this would have on culture and so forth, I would consider accepting an answer where this combination (FTL or instantaneous communication with no FTL travel) existed in the world/universe for a significant amount of time (enough to influence the culture significantly, say, a few generations at least), and FTL travel was discovered later (and the book or series explores the period before FTL travel, rather than mentioning it as a historical tidbit).

We have seen in [my earlier question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/250338/what-is-the-earliest-story-or-book-combining-ftl-communication-with-lack-of-ftl) that there are some very interesting earlier examples of a similar dynamic where the communication is telepathic.  I am also interested in finding earlier examples of this concept where the communication is solved by a technological breakthrough in communications, which is not matched with a similar breakthrough in physical travel.

Were there earlier examples of this than the ones I mentioned above? What (and when!) is the earliest example?

NOTE:  OSC mentions (same source as above) that he encountered this concept in a short story where all messages were preceded by a beep, which, when analyzed, turned out to contain all messages ever sent by this method, past and future.  This story appears to be identified in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/104330/59154), as the 1954 James Blish story, "Beep".  However, I have skimmed parts of the story and they did actually have FTL travel; the similarity is that FTL travel still took weeks or months while the Dirac communicator was instantaneous.

Comment: Wikipedia mentions the interocitor from *This Island Earth* but they apparently also had FTL travel, since they were able to visit Metaluna and return to the same Earth, not one centuries older...

Comment: Looks like *Foundation* (serialized 1942-1944) had "hyperwave" but also "hyperspace jumps".

Comment: And Doc Smith had FTL ships as early as the late 1920s, never had comms without them AFAIK.

Comment: There were apparently some [short stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fisherman_of_the_Inland_Sea) in the Hainish cycle that featured people traveling faster than light using new developments in "Churten theory", though from reading some of the descriptions it sounds like it had harmful effects on those who made the jump so maybe that's why it didn't become widespread (also these stories were written later than the more famous Hainish cycle stories like *The Dispossessed* so maybe you could still say those earlier stories would qualify).

Comment: Also, even in earlier Hainish stories I believe it was possible to transport non-living matter FTL, just not people--would this count in terms of what you're asking for? If anyone can find an earlier example of FTL communication without FTL travel prior to the earliest Hainish stories (*Rocannon's World* and *Planet of Exile* from 1966) it probably wouldn't have this feature, so it might not matter.

Comment: People are what is important, from my perspective.

Comment: Ender's Game most certainly has FTL travel. It just has faster comms.

Comment: @Valorum - where?  From the conversation between Graff and Ender, on the way to Eros, it certainly doesn't sound like that.  They discovered from the buggers that FTL communication was possible ("We knew then that it was possible. To communicate faster than light. ", and they did it.  But they sent the ships toward the bugger homeworld as soon as they had this; it took them about 75 years to arrive; their breakthrough was FTL communication, not travel.

Comment: @Basya - Ignoring the execrable sequels, Graf talks about how more modern ships are able to go even faster

Comment: Faster than the old ships, or faster than light?  Where does it actually say FTL travel was achieved?

Comment: After the war, when Valentine meets Ender and tells him that she will be going to the first colony, Ender says "It's fifty years to get there".  Her answer, "Only two years if you're aboard the ship".  This does not sound like FTL travel; it sounds like 'normal', relativistic travel to me.  And I remember much the same in Speaker for the Dead as well, though I didn't look today.

Comment: In Speaker for the Dead, where we see that Ender has been around for thousands of years due to the relativistic effects of travel, it is referred to as "Lightspeed travel"

Comment: Later in Speaker for the Dead, on the trip to Lusitania, it is mentioned "the only task was to calculate how near to lightspeed the trip was traveling".

Comment: "Rocannon's World" by Ursula K. Le Guin: FTL communication, FTL ships (not allowing life onboard), and "close to light speed ships" - allowing life on board - 117 pages.

Comment: @Basya - In the books that directly follow Speaker for the Dead, they learn to use psychic powers to jump instantaneously from place to place. FTL is most certainly a thing, although Card basically retconned that out of future novels.

Comment: @Valorum - I don't think it was in Xenocide either.  After that I don't know; but it doesn't really matter....the fact that there are other books in the series which have FTL travel does not change the fact that Ender's Game/Speaker for the Dead don't have it.  So there are at least two books (though Ursula Le Guin  certainly beat him to it.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - I believe that is the first book in the Hainish Cycle, no?  If so, it is the earliest book in the running at the moment.

Comment: @Basya it is from 1966

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - as I wrote in my question, yes, 1966.  So far that is the best option...

Comment: @Valorum - I take back one thing I said; the instantaneous travel is at the end of Xenocide.

Comment: @Hypnosifl - you mentioned the ultrawave/Dirac communicator in a comment on my related question.  I have not read those stories, and I have not been able to tell from descriptions, whether people were restricted to below-lightspeed travel.  Do you know the answer to that question?  Because, if they did have that restriction, it might be a good answer to this question; at least some of the stories using this were earlier than the Hainish cycle.

Comment: Wikipedia's article on the [ansible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansible) mentions many of the same stories from the comments, and nothing earlier.

Comment: @TzeraFNX - if that is the case, and no one comes up with anything earlier, we have Ursula LeGuin to thank for introducing this idea (which fascinates me!).  Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, she introduced the word, "ansible", though, so the concept could have existed earlier, but with a different name.

Comment: "instantaneous (or, almost) communication" was the stuff of fantasy until [Aug 5, 1858](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/first-transatlantic-telegraph-cable-completed) when the first trans-Atlantic telegraph cable was completed. You could have a basically real-time conversation between New York and London, while physical travel between the two was a nearly 2-week journey by boat. Sure, it wasn't _years_, but it was faster than anything prior.

Comment: Heinlein's [Time For The Stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_for_the_Stars), published in 1956, has relativistic travel, but instantaneous communication via telepathy. The telepaths are (mostly) identical twins.

Comment: There are also stories with the opposite scenario: FTL travel but no FTL "radio", so messages travel by mail, with high priority comms sent on special messenger probes.

Comment: @PM2Ring - thanks!  See the linked question; Heinlein was late to the party for this scenario with telepathy.

Comment: @PM2Ring - Interesting, the opposite scenario.  The story I mentioned, "Beep", before the invention of the Dirac communicator, had a similar scenario, but both were FTL, just the ships were significantly faster than the ultrawave.  It is an interesting scenario as well.

Comment: I didn't post *Time For The Stars* as an answer because the *Venus Equilateral* stories are earlier, but I figured it deserves a mention in the comments. ;) FWIW, I read *Beep* in the early 1970s.

Comment: @PM2Ring- - thanks.  It wouldn't have been an answer to this question because I specified "technological" -- I was trying to rule out telepathic, as that was answered (surprising me!) in my previous question.  This has been a very interesting discussion.

Answer (score 7):

In George O. Smith's [Venus Equilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Equilateral) stories (mostly published in *Astounding* in the early 1940s), there was a background element of STL interplanetary travel. The resourceful engineers at the Venus Equilateral space station routinely invent revolutionary new technologies. In one of the stories, "Beam Pirate" (October, 1944), they come up with a faster-than-light communications method.

Comment: Cool!  That is significantly earlier even than "Beep", which had inspired OSC but which actually had FTL travel, just not near the communication speed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have been able to find, the earliest example is indeed Ursula LeGuin's Hainish cycle, where travel is below the speed of light and with relativistic effects) but communication is instantaneous via the ansible.